# json parsererror

Tags: json

why this error

xhr: [object XMLHttpRequest]
 textStatus: parsererror
 errorThrown: Invalid JSON: [ { "id": "10000000", "label": "10000000" }, { "id": "10000001", "label": "10000001" }, { "id": "10000003", "label": "10000003" }, { "id": "10000005", "label": "10000005" }, { "id": "10000006", "label": "10000006" } ]

Comment: What's parsing the JSON? (which browser, language implementation, or library, for example)

Answer (score 1):

Copied and pasted this:

`[ { "id": "10000000", "label": "10000000" }, { "id": "10000001", "label": "10000001" }, { "id": "10000003", "label": "10000003" }, { "id": "10000005", "label": "10000005" }, { "id": "10000006", "label": "10000006" }]`

to [JSONlint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) and it says it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the original JSON if that is the original then the it is missing a root key

```
var textStatus = {"keys":[{"id":"...", "label":"..."},{"id":"...","label":"..."}]}
```

Also the whole thing needs to be inside {} to make it an object what you had is just an array

Comment: Per http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt (I just found it existed :-) the root can be either an *object* or an *array*. The parser in question may not grok it (for whatever reason) though. JSON.org itself seems very non-committal in the details.